# How to implement and use cordova plugin dialog in Ionic Creator

Tags: ionic-framework

I’m using ionic creator to create an android app. How can I use Cordova plugin dialogs in the creator?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: [Follow these steps](https://docs.usecreator.com/docs/how-to-use-cordova-plugins-with-your-creator-app) after add [this native plugins](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/dialogs/) in your project.